# Window analogous to pages

Tags: wpf

I created a window which has **"Loaded"**  and **"Closing"** events in .xaml file , now i want to change window to page  for that "Loaded" i.e. Page_Loading" exist but there is no "Closing"tag available , is there any alternative for that

For windows

```
Title="MainWindow" Height="464" Width="733" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing" >
```

For page

```
Title="Page1" Height="464" Width="733" Loaded="Page_Loaded"  >
```

Closing doesnt exist for page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However there is the event

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Exit
```

which is raised with both Window and Page

Or consider that the event

```
Unloaded
```

is both in Window and Page